# How to read dependency tree generated by gradle

Tags: android, maven, gradle, dependencies

I run ./gradlew app:dependencies and got a dependency tree. However, I don't know what +--- and /--- mean. Googled for a while but with no luck.

And my question is what does +--- and /--- mean in dependcy tree? The following is a sample dependency tree:

```
compile
+--- project :api
|    \--- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4
\--- commons-io:commons-io:1.2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\---` and `+---` are used to show the elements within a dependency tree. The only difference between `+---` and `\---` is that  `\---` is used to show the last element of the current dependecy level. So, it could look somthing like:

```
org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs:3.0.3
+--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-core:3.0.3 (*)
+--- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.0.1
+--- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2
\--- org.apache.cxf:cxf-rt-transports-http:3.0.3 (*)
```

And this means, that `cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs` depends on 4 libraries. And the `cxf-rt-transports-http` is the last one from the first level dependencies of the root.

Furthermore, you may have some transitive dependencies. That is the case, you have with your `:api` project, then the root project depends on `:api` and `:api` itself depends in `org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4`.